# Spring Boot - using environment variables in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to parametrize my `application.yml` file so I can put it on github repo with my project, but not reveal database connection details. I want to use system environment variables to do so. I use OS X El Capitan.

I put following lines in my `.bash_profile`:

```
export JDBC_TODO_USER=<my-username>
export JDBC_TODO_PASS=<my-password>
```

and following lines in my `application.yml`:

```
spring:
   datasource:
   username: ${JDBC_TODO_USER}
   password: ${JDBC_TODO_PASS}
```

I also tried

```
spring:
   datasource:
   username: ${JDBC.TODO.USER}
   password: ${JDBC.TODO.PASS}
```

Both of those give me an error during start of the app:
`java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Could not connect: Access denied for user '${JDBC_TODO_USER'@'<my-ip-address>' (using password: YES)`

Of course, when I replace `${JDBC_TODO_USER}` with my username and `${JDBC_TODO_PASS}` with my password then everything works fine. It looks like Spring does not understand that I refer to environment variables. Do I need to do some additional configuration to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprit - I did everything through Eclipse and Eclipse does not see what's inside `.bash_profile` file. Setting those environment variables in Run -> Run Configuratons... -> Environment fixed the issue.

Comment: It's the same with IntelliJ IDEA as well. Thank you for sharing. it took me 1 week to eventually to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

It is quite likely that your environment variables are not being made available. Have you tried the following to see if they are accessible?

```
echo $JDBC_TODO_USER
echo $JDBC_TODO_PASS
```

or

```
export
```

A sure-fire way to ensure they are available is to:

1. sudo vi /etc/launchd.conf
2. Add the following lines:

> ```
> setenv JDBC_TODO_USER 
> setenv JDBC_TODO_PASS
> ```

3. Save the file.
4. Run **export** to confirm that your entries are there

You can also try system properties:

java -Djdbc.todo.user=myuser -Djdbc.todo.pass=mypass -jar MyProject.jar

with the following in your application.yml:

```
spring:
   datasource:
   username: ${jdbc.todo.user}
   password: ${jdbc.todo.pass}
```

But ultimately for storing user credentials in a production environment I would recommend one of the following:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html
https://vaultproject.io/

Comment: As I wrote in my own answer, the problem was with Eclipse not seeing variables defined in `.bash_profile`. I noticed that when I ran `mvn spring-boot:run` in Terminal and the app started without any problem. I had to set those variables inside Run Configuration in Eclipse to make it work there. But thank you for pointing out other ways of passing those credentials!

Comment: This works when using a Java properties file too. I would just like to point out that when relying on environment variables you have to make it clear they exist beforehand (eg. watch out on Win env's).